# apktool decompile but wont recompile

Tags: apktool

i have try apkeasytool and advancedapktoot got the same problem
this a simple example

Log For : 1Multiplication.apk

Log Type : Recompiling

Log Recorded At : Sun 22-09-2019 0:17:37.78

Log Recorded By : Advanced ApkTool v4.1.0 By BDFreak

---

brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = -1073741515): [C:\Users\HALLOUMI\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_6451159325101765518.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 15, --target-sdk-version, 28, --version-code, 25, --version-name, 2.3.7, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\HALLOUMI\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL2211348455311856190.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, META-INF/android.arch.core_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_livedata-core.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_viewmodel.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.core_core.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.drawerlayout_drawerlayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.print_print.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.slidingpanelayout_slidingpanelayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable-animated.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version, -0, META-INF/androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-hdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-mdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_focused_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_longpressed_holo.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_primary_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_scrubber_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha.9.png, -0, mp3, -0, arsc, -I, C:\AdvancedApkTool\1-BDFreak\Frameworks\1.apk, -S, C:\AdvancedApkTool\3-Out\1Multiplication.apk\res, -M, C:\AdvancedApkTool\3-Out\1Multiplication.apk\AndroidManifest.xml]

---

Comment: The question is not well formatted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: when i decompile via "apktool d" its work than i don t make any modification on the folder  but when i want to recompile using "apktool b" i got that message you see  i try everything still not success if you have any info about that tell me

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution that is.
create folder c: \ Myapk
contain: 
apktool . bat
apktool . jar
baksmali . jar
smali . jar
create framework in appdata \ local\ apktool\ framework\ 1 . apk manual

i put my file tst . apk also i used the command 
apktool -r d test . apk
and its work when i use command apktool b test 
the app is creating successfully
my question is
 ** why didn't work with
command  apktool d
?
***and if i can make change in Advancedapktool to make it easy for me?